# Force format USB

Tags: partitioning, usb, usb-drive

Maybe you can help me but I'm becoming very doubtful. But I have a Verbatim flash drive (third Verbatim flash drive to do this to be exact and one sandisk all the same problem over the past year) But using them between Windows machines and Linux machines switching between the two they eventually be come corrupt and no amount of software can fix them that I have found and the more I try to format them whether on windows or linux they just keep getting more and more errors each time till I give up.

Any way I will just tell you my problems from the one that messed up last night. I reinstalled windows on a customers computer so I backed up the drivers to the the USB stick and transferred them to my ubuntu desktop and then used Ubuntu to make the USB bootable to install windows and it went flawless. However I reformatted the drive and slid the drivers for windows back on it appeared to have worked only some of the files weren't making it to the usb drive tried like 10 times each time different files were missing even though Ubuntu said it was successful. I formatted the drive multiple times during the process and eventually the flash drive started getting errors on both computers. Windows kept saying it couldn't read it and needed to format it and Ubuntu kept getting all kinds of errors under gparted. Anyway I've tried dd, disk utility, gparted, fsck. At this point it is so bad it don't matter what I try or what command I use it always comes back as read-only and it wont do anything to it. I don't currently have access to a windows machine I have a windows 7 virtual machine but it crashes as soon as I plug in the drive.

Comment: Have you tried using `gparted` and formatting the drive `fat32` what happens? Also how old is the flash drive? This also may be of use: http://superuser.com/questions/376274/check-the-physical-health-of-a-usb-stick-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this with a 4GB Verbatim USB which, funnily enough, is sitting right next to me as I type this with Windows 7.iso mounted on it.

The program I used to fix it is a very small, compact yet extremely fast and powerful software from http://rufus.akeo.ie/

The program is called Rufus and it can mount .iso's for Windows, Ubuntu and I believe Os x too.

Basically, install the software, plug your USB in and choose a format etc. (the .iso locator is 
the small button next to the .iso text) and then with the size, make sure you choose how ever many GB's your USB is.

Give it a shot and see how it goes, worked for me.

Comment: That's what I used to make the windows 7 on it bootable before it messed up. I don't have access to a window machine at the moment I have 3 computers and all run Ubuntu. I set up at windows 7 virtual machine thinking it would cover what ever I needed windows for that Ubuntu couldn't do but as I said for some reason it crashes as soon as I plug the USB in.

Comment: @SamTarkington Damn, sounds like your USB might just be ruined. They are only around $8. Might be time for a newie :)

Comment: Its just funny that they don't last no time. I originally got them about 3 months a go to use with 3 Raspberry Pi running xbmc then I just switched them to use only SD cards. In just a matter of months all 3 flash drives have bit the dust.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a thumb drive that would not show up.  I tried gparted several times after the startuup disk program would not write to the drive.  /what I finally found using gparted, if using the drop down under devise, Create a new partition, make sure you are on the correct drive,  in my case that was SBD,  nothing seems to happen, so I tried again, only to have nothing seem to happen. so I went to the next drop down which I had also tried before. That menu is partition, now when I went to create a new partition, I was easily able to make an MSDOS partition. Then the startup program worked perfectly.   I have not tried some thing esle yuet but I'm betting that now that I have an DOS partition I can convert it to an ext.  Just my experience. I realize this thread is several years old, but I did not see that there had been a resolution. I hope this helps some one with the same issue from haveing to go out and spend $8 and extra time on a new thumb drive.